# Engine fault service engine now

Tags: ford, starter, focus

I have a 2014 Ford Focus
 I have been having issues with my horn not working and I called the place I bought my car they told me to check the relay so pulled it out put it back in and it worked. Fast forward a couple weeks and it happened again no horn so I pulled the relay out put it back in and this time nothing so my friend pulled out three relays and put them back in, that’s when I got in my car turned the key to start it and the “engine fault service engine now” popped up on my dash now my car won’t start nor will it turn over, the three relays that were pulled was the starter relay the air conditioning clutch relay, and the horn relay. All the things I have tried were disconnect the battery, buy all three of those relays brand new, turn the key on for 20 mins and then try and it still will not start the windows won’t roll down and the horn still isn’t working either.

What could be the issue(s)?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Either your buddy put a bad relay inplace of the start relay, or the jiggling of relays point to another problem - likely loose connection.

Take a known working relay and swap it for the starter relay, if it fixes things, great.

If not, take a second to examine the fuse box itself.  Should have nice tight connections and if you check with a volt meter, should have 12-13.6V on the input (direct from batter).

Then examine all the fuses in that box, make sure they are good.  Auto parts stores have quick little fuse checkers.  Worth a couple of bucks.

I'm not sure about that car, but typically power windows are not on a relay in the engine compartment.  I could be wrong - check the labels.  If there is a issue, maybe your buddy pulled the wrong relays?  Maybe power window failure is just a coincidence?

Does the radio work?  Dash lights? etc. etc.

One last thing with the starter, all cars have some sort of neutral safety switch - on automatics you should only be able to start in park or neutral.  Most manuals have a switch on the clutch pedal.  So 3 things must work - ignition switch, neutral safety switch and starter relay.  That should be enough to here at least an audible click.

Good luck